# C Function/object not returning consistent output when spam executing

Tags: c, printf, stdout

I am working on a mini project that stores it's database in a local file and manipulates it. I'm still new to programming so this randomness of output is out of my expertise to debug. The code as of the moment is large so I will just paste what is relevant.

```
extern void returnRecord(FILE *fp, fpos_t pos, char *retArr)
{ 
  char tok = delim;  //for strtok (delimiter = control char 21)
  char tmpArr[612]; //for strtok
  char *segment;     //pointer to save strtok return
  fsetpos(fp, &pos);  //beginning of the record
  fgets(tmpArr, 611, fp); 
  strtok(tmpArr,&tok);
  strcpy(retArr, tmpArr);
  strcat(retArr, "\n");
  segment = strtok(NULL, &tok); //tmpArr now has the author name

  int tmpCount = 0;
  char c = segment[0];
  int counter = strlen(retArr);
  while((c != 6) && (c != 0))
    {
      retArr[counter++] = c;
      c = segment[++tmpCount];
    }
  retArr[counter++] = '\n';



  segment = strtok(NULL, &tok); //tmpArr now has the rack number

  tmpCount = 0;
  c = segment[tmpCount++];
  while((c != 6) && (c != 0))
    {
      retArr[counter++] = c;
      c = segment[tmpCount++];
    }

  retArr[counter++] = '\n';


  segment = strtok(NULL, &tok); //tmpArr now has the book title

  tmpCount = 0;
  c = segment[tmpCount++];
  while((c != 6) && (c != 0) && (c != '\n'))
    {
      retArr[counter++] = c;
      c = segment[tmpCount++];
    }

  retArr[counter] = '\0';
  return;
}
```

The below is not C but the description for a sample record in my database:

```
<...> everything inside is my explanation
<6s> means a bunch of buffer characters that are all 0x06

3<delim>Isaac Newton<6s><delim>3<6s><delim>Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica<6s><new line only if it's not the final record>

(delim is: #define delim 21 //at the top)
```

There probably are some redundancies, but optimisation is not my immediate concern because the output (char *retArr) is not always consistent. Here  are some of my outputs when spamming the executable.

```
printf("%s\n strlen: %d\n", ret2, strlen(ret2)); //print code
```

```
(the first execution here shows the full correct output)
sflash@debian:~/Documents/AOHI/experimental/books$ ./exe
6
Stress test | boooiafnakekjfn/;
4124
e0q-pjrnoibq3uitu0o;@lt@qjtoilqnkubneugbq3tq3
 strlen: 84
sflash@debian:~/Documents/AOHI/experimental/books$ ./exe
6
Stress test | boooiafnakekjfn/;
41245
e0q-pjrn
 strlen: 48
sflash@debian:~/Documents/AOHI/experimental/books$ ./exe
6
Stress test | boooiafnakekjfn/;
41
45
 strlen: 39
```

The code seems to be jumping some iterations when I rapidly run the program. It is pretty important to fix this because I intend to call this function/object inside loops.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: To begin with, `fgets(tmpArr, 611, fp)` can overflow the buffer. And `strtok(NULL, &tok)` is invalid since `&tok` isn't a null-terminated string.

Comment: fgets handles null character, but yeah buffer overflow was a problem. But the problem still persists even after I expanded the relevant array sizes

Comment: At this point I'd be happy to see a SIGSEGV because I can then pinpoint.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that 611 is greater than 610? Just asking.

Comment: As I said above I fixed it, but it is not the problem. The while loops in my code seems to be prematurely meeting the end conditions. I'm trying to figure out the cause.

Comment: Have you fixed the `&tok` issue when calling `strtok` as well?

Comment: I just did, and now it works fine now after looping it a 100 times. Didn't realize it was the main problem in my code. My bad, I should have read the C standard more carefully next time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was as pointed by Some programmer dude, I have been using strtok() wrong and mismatching array sizes. The delimiter has to be terminated by a NULL character.